# Sum today from 00:00 to 23:59

Tags: mysql

Can someone please help me make the query more precise.

Currently it sums from the current time to yesterday that time. Instead I want a more exact 1 day time frame from 00:00 to 23:59 today.

Please keep the code simple.

Thank you

```
SELECT name, SUM(quantity)
    FROM downloads d
WHERE date BETWEEN DATE_SUB( now() , INTERVAL 1 DAY ) AND NOW()
```

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [CURRENT_DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-date) function, that will return the current date of today, without time info:

```
SELECT name, SUM(quantity)
FROM downloads d
WHERE
  date>=CURRENT_DATE()
  AND date<CURRENT_DATE() + INTERVAL '1' DAY
```

Please notice that you are selecting the `name` column, which is not aggregated. You might want to remove it from the SELECT, or add a `GROUP BY name` clause, but which one is better depends on your intentions.

I prefer this solution over a `WHERE DATE(date) = CURRENT_DATE()` as my solution can make use of an index and has better performances.

Comment: @Strawberry maybe the name should be better removed from the select, but what else?